# Where are the secret rooms in a Minecraft woodland mansion?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have heard that there are secret rooms in woodland mansions. I searched forever but could not find any.

Comment: What have you tried to find it?

Comment: In some cases you could find secret rooms by checking all the windows of the woodland mansion, as even though they're almost always hiden behind the walls inside the mansion, there's nothing that stops the secret rooms from generating next to a window.

Answer (score 2):

To access secret rooms, you **must** mine into the walls of the mansion to find them. Some mansions have many secret rooms, while others only have a few. These rooms include:

- A diamond block encased in 2 layers of obsidian
- A diamond block encased in lava and a glass wall
- A room with nothing but a chest
- A room with many cobwebs and a spider spawner
- And much more!

Check out [this site](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Woodland_Mansion#Main_rooms) to see more about the secret rooms. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, there could be many or only a few secret rooms. But could there be *no secret rooms* at all?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Yes. The mansions generation is random and if you're particularly unlucky none of these will generate. This is quite unlikely but possible. Chance none of the *good ones* generates are higher.